# Are card drops equally likely?

Tags: steam, steam-trading-cards

Are all card drops equally likely? The number of the market seem a little too much off, what with there being six thousand more Football Manager cards for sale than anything else.

[image]

Comment: why is this downvoted so bad?

Comment: My main reason is that it amounts to trivia. Plus, all the math in the world won't make me confident of the answer, because this isn't a site for math experts.

Comment: @Sterno for what it's worth [I actually asked "math experts" to review what I wrote](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/10427109#10427109)

Comment: My point is that unlike most gaming questions, this community is not particularly well qualified to judge the accuracy or merit of answers based on statistical analysis, and thus weigh in appropriately with votes (as evidenced by the fact that a possibly completely correct answer is sitting at -3). That you did ask math guys to check it is commendable, though.

Comment: @Sterno Thing is, without these maths I wouldn't be able to _prove_ the claim! It's not show-off, it's now rep whoring, it's just necessary because the whole thing is kind of counterintuitive and the numbers _feel_ close enough without _being_ so.

Comment: That's my point! Its a question that this community is not designed to be able to answer or judge the answers of. The score of any answer to this question will likely have little to do with the answer's accuracy. And note I'm talking about my reason for down voting the question, not the answer (which I have neither upvoted nor downvoted). Anyway, that's my reason, agree or not. I can't speak for any of the other voters.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The short answer is: No, they are not.

The long answer follows.

First off, why pay attention to the Steam Market numbers? It's the closest approximation to the real thing we have, and while it is skewed in a way, we must make do with it.

We can consider three kinds of users:

- **Opportunists.** They want the badge, so they'll sell dupes and use the revenue to buy the cards they need.
- **Scrooges.** They don't want the badge, but they like the idea of making money from this situation, so they'll sell all the cards they get for real money. (I am in this group.)
- **Traders.** They will never sell or buy a card to the Steam Market. They don't use the market at all, either because they don't care, or because they don't need it.

Since no one card is more special than the others, there is no rational need to cling on some cards and discard others. Only the full set of cards is useful. Any set of nine cards is equally pointless to hold onto.

We don't need to care too much about estimating the proportions between these user groups, the amount of cards each gets and the amount of cards each sells because we can only assume that card distribution does not change based on what kind of user  you are. The only difference is that, if card drops are uniformly dropped, the dupes they'll sell and buy on the market will also be uniformly dropped; otherwise, they won't. Since the hypothesis is "card drops are dropping uniformly" we don't need, or *want*, to try and adjust for this skew that shouldn't be there in the first place.

Now, there's a fairly easy way to tell if a distribution of cards like this is uniform or not. It's called the [Pearson's Chi Squared](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pearson%27s_chi-squared_test) test. It's based on this formula:

[image]

You take the difference between the expected number of cards *E* and the observed number of cards *O* for each kind, square it, divide it by *E* and sum the results. If the result is "small enough", the test is passed. How small is small enough?

My reference material on Statistics says that it needs to be smaller than the (1-α)th percentile of the [χ² distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chi-squared_distribution) with 10 − 1 = 9 degrees of freedom. Realistically, we can find the value of α where the two quantities are the same (the so-called [p-value](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P-value)); if α is close to 0, the expected distribution is "wrong"; if α is close to 1, observation matches expectation.

Well, let's run the numbers. While you could do this on any game, I chose to run the numbers on the Steam Trading Cards set for one main good reasons: there's a LOT of cards out there, which lets us be very precise. If I took the TF2 cards, for example, I'd only have a quarter of the data to work with (100k instead of 400k). Additionally, it lets me dismiss counterarguments that can be made about holding onto specific cards; more about that later.

For those who can't see images, the value of α is about 10^-66 (that's 0.000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001). Ignoring the "outliers" in the group, Football Manager and Skyrim, doesn't get us appreciably closer to 1.

(Scroll down the image, I'm not done here.)

[image]

What does that 10^-66 number mean anyway? Wikipedia [says](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P-value) *(annotations in italic are mine)*:

> One often "rejects the null hypothesis" *(= cards drop evenly)* when the p-value is less than the predetermined significance level which is often 0.05 or 0.01, indicating that the observed result would be highly unlikely under the null hypothesis (i.e., the observation is highly unlikely to be the result of random chance). Many common statistical tests, such as chi-squared tests *(what I used)* or Student's t-test, produce test statistics which can be interpreted using p-values.

In other words, it's 0.00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001% likely that the difference in the numbers is due to really bad luck.

"But badp," I hear you cry. "Some of those games are more popular than others. It's obvious that the cards of the more popular games are more sought after than the rest! Who the hell likes soccer anyway?" It turns out roughly as many people like dragons as they like soccer; just look at the publicly available numbers for [how many people are playing what games](http://store.steampowered.com/stats/). Skyrim and Football Manager are close to the top, and yet *there are 26% more Football Manager cards than Skyrim cards.* Actually running the number, again, gives us little doubt on the matter: ([see the numbers without outliers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7tu8t.png))

[image]

What does .229 mean? Let's see [what this page has to say](http://www.surveysystem.com/correlation.htm):

> While correlation coefficients are normally reported as r = (a value between -1 and +1), squaring them makes then easier to understand. The square of the coefficient (or r square) is equal to the percent of the variation in one variable that is related to the variation in the other. After squaring r, ignore the decimal point. An r of .5 means 25% of the variation is related (.5 squared =.25). An r value of .7 means 49% of the variance is related (.7 squared = .49).

Here r² = 0.052. In other words, a difference of 1% in popularity would mean a 0.05% difference in cards available on the market. That's very weak correlation, and that shouldn't be surprising: each card, on its own, is pretty much worthless. Only the full set is useful. You know what's a better way to show your allegiance to a game rather than another? *Crafting a game badge for it, [then showing it off on your profile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u5hjK.png).* Or *being level 10 and [featuring it for free on your profile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HTHfL.png).*

Now, there'd be no such equivalent for this argument if I ran the same numbers on TF2. You *could* argue that somebody would hold onto Engineer cards because they love playing Engineer. It still sounds dumb, but the above counterpoint doesn't apply. OTOH, the numbers are still pretty clear there as well:

[image]

Okay, how about a game with a ton of different cards? [McPixel comes to the rescue.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j86XE.png) Prefer a game with fewer ones? [Torchlight only has 6 and the results are kind of glaring.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7T1Ob.png)

It would be easy to speculate on *why* this is the case. It could be a bug [the likes of which we've heard about with Microsoft](http://www.robweir.com/blog/2010/02/microsoft-random-browser-ballot.html). It could be intentional in order to create a more interesting economy where not everything is worth precisely as much as everything else, and let entrepreneuring users try and invest money in the system (remember, Steam gets a cut of *all* transactions; more transactions, more cuts.) It doesn't really matter though. I hope it's now clear that it's a fact: card drops are not equally likely across the board.

Comment: There's at least one group of people you're not accounting for: Marketeers, who try to arbitrage.

Comment: @fbueckert The Steam Market offers very little room for arbitry - especially upwards, which is the only kind of arbitry that's useful for people who own the loads of cards you need to game the market in the first place. With prices decreasing and only the top 10 offers being visible at any one point, there's not a Whole lot you can do to sell for more than you buy.

Comment: Sell 10 cards for $.05 and you might get somebody to put theirs for $.07 or even $.04, but the effect will only last for a few seconds, given the speed at which transactions happen.

Comment: Here's a group you're forgetting about: **Idiots**, who have no idea how this trading card stuff works, get a card for a game they don't like (Football Manager), and sell it for what Steam tells them it's worth to buy a card for a game they do like (Skyrim) for roughly the same amount of money.

Comment: In other words, I find fault with the assumption that this is a marketplace full of rational and well informed actors.

Comment: @LessPop_MoreFizz Fine, let's consider idiots. Idiots operate _completely at random_ with the cards they've got. If they get _equally-random cards_ though, they'll end up buying and selling cards that are also _equally-random._ Of course the marketplace isn't full of rational actors, but the fundamental point here is that no one card is "more useful" than others. If cards are equally distributed, demand and offer are equal across the board.

Comment: @badp But idiots *aren't* completely random, if, instead, they exhibit a bias correlated to the *popularity of various games*.

Comment: @LessPop_MoreFizz [Skyrim and Football Manager are roughly as popular and quite a lot more popular than the rest of the game with cards.](http://store.steampowered.com/stats/) Yet, there's an abudance of Football Manager and a lack of Skyrim. Your hypothesis doesn't match reality.

Comment: -1 What you've just shown is that the cards don't have an equal probability of selling on the market, not that they don't have an equal probability of being dropped.  I find @LessPop_MoreFizz's selection-bias explanation **much** more plausible than the claim that Valve arbitrarily decided to make Football Manager card-drops 1% more likely *(and Bioshock Infinite and Skyrim, two extremely popular games, less likely)* than all the other cards.

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft Maybe you aren't aware that there is also no uniform distribution in TF2 unusuals. Both [effects](http://stats.tf/particles) and [unusuals](http://stats.tf/cat/hats/5) differ in rarity, even between hats and unusuals that were released together. It'd certainly not be a first for them.

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft LessPop's explanation _does not find root in reality_ unfortunately. Sorry to break it to you, but just as many people like dragons as they like soccer players - and yet, Skyrim and Football Manager differ by _nine thousand cards._ __There are 26% more Football Manager cards around than Skyrim cards, and I'm yet to hear another reason why this would be the case.__

Comment: It's certainly possible that card-frequencies on the market are a direct indication of how they're dropped, but it's unlikely; **there are just too many confounding factors**.  Besides the popularity of the games *(which is not shown in your link - that's only the number of current players, which obviously depends on the age and replay value of the game)*, you have to consider:  (cont)

Comment: (1) **Where** the games are popular - certain areas might be willing to spend more on decorative cards than others *(Skyrim/Bioshock Infinite are **way** more popular than Football Manager here in the US, and we tend to be spendthrifts for useless crap)*; (2) What kinds of players play each game *(I'd be willing to bet Skyrim and BI players are more hardcore-gamers than FM, on average)*; and, (3) The cost of each card on the market, which is affected by even more (often completely random) economic factors than I've listed here.

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft I didn't look at the cost of cards because there's nearly not enough precision there to extract anything useful, but (very much like popularity) Skyrim and Football Manager cards are _both_ selling for €0.10. Make that of it what you want; I think the price point data is way too coarse to be useful. As for 1) and 2) that's hot hair until you can find some source for those claims. I've sourced all of my claims; it's only fair you do the same.

Comment: ? There is nothing for me to source - those *are* potential confounding variables that need to be taken into account, before anyone can correctly come to the conclusion that you drew.  My comments *(  )* were just examples of how those things could possibly skew the results.

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft There's nothing then for me to source when saying that what you're arguing is certainly a factor but such a minuscule factor that can go both ways, it hardly matters and certainly isn't enough to explain a 26% difference.

Comment: ...Well I think they could easily account for a 26% difference.  But until we take them into account to know either way, we cannot come to the conclusion that you drew.

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft That's your argument and the onus of the proof is on you. I've taken the liberty of proving for you that the good-sounding popularity argument is actually completely irrelevant and I'm confident in thinking that those other arguments are even less relevant.

Comment: «Overall it looks like a good analysis, well-explained for the audience. You got the right chi-squared statistic at the outset. Removing the "outliers" and re-running the test is not justifiable but it didn't lead you astray. The correlation analysis is neither necessary nor advisable: a glance at the scatterplot says it all, anyway. If you wanted to drive home your message and make the lack of association even clearer you could start the y-axis values at zero.» – [whuber](http://stats.stackexchange.com/users/919/), [here](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/10427109#10427109)