# CS:GO Anarchist trading card

Tags: counter-strike-global-offensive, steam-trading-cards

I noticed that every once in a while I will get a trading card as I play CS:GO. I have everything but the Anarchist trading card and was wondering what the drop chances are for that?

Is there anything special I need to do to obtain this one? I understand I can probably just buy it or trade for it but I want to know my other options.

Comment: Related: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/124694/are-card-drops-equally-likely, and perhaps, http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/117440/how-do-i-pick-up-trading-cards

Comment: Darn, I was really hoping it wouldn't be as random and that I could target specific cards I need without trading or buying. Thanks Frank

Comment: You will always have to spend some money to get some of the cards if I am not mistaken. The max drop (excluding games where you can put money onto them )is usally less than the amount needed to complete the set, and duplicates tend to happen. And with games with their own store that you can spend money on, you have to spend more money on the game (through Steam) to get more drops.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All steam trading cards are random drops. There is no guarantee that you will get a specific card as a drop or in packs that you receive.